# java/parse error. trying to send from android sdk to Parse

Tags: java, android, heroku, parse-platform, sdk

set up this for another app few days ago and it worked fine, results successfully sent to MongoLab.
tried to do it again for a new app using the same basic code below, but it fails everytime.

Any ideas? Thanks!

```
 @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    // Enable Local Datastore.
    Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);

    // Add your initialization code here
    Parse.initialize(new Parse.Configuration.Builder(getApplicationContext())
            .applicationId("abc123")
            .clientKey(null)
            .server("http://abc123.herokuapp.com/parse/")
    .build()
    );

      ParseObject gameScore = new ParseObject("GameScore");
      gameScore.put("score", 1337);
      gameScore.put("playerName", "Sean Plott");
      gameScore.put("cheatMode", false);
      gameScore.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
          public void done(ParseException e) {
              if (e == null) {
                  Log.i("Parse", "Save Succeeded");
              } else {
                  Log.i("Parse", "Save Failed");
              }
          }
      });
```

------the logs show this at the end---------

```
D/InputMethodManagerService: ime_enabled = false is same as last value, no change
W/InputMethodManagerService: Got RemoteException sending setActive(false) notification to pid 23566 uid 10087
I/ActivityManager: Displayed com.parse.starter/.MainActivity: +410ms (total +10m33s240ms)
D/WindowManager: topDisplayedActivityInfo, appToken: Token{2e99c6e0 ActivityRecord{2e79b238 u0 com.parse.starter/.MainActivity t19}}
W/System: Ignoring header X-Parse-Client-Key because its value was null.
W/System: Ignoring header X-Parse-Client-Key because its value was null.
W/System: Ignoring header X-Parse-Client-Key because its value was null.
D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 600K, 25% free 2735K/3644K, paused 10ms, total 10ms
W/System: Ignoring header X-Parse-Client-Key because its value was null.
I/Parse: Save Failed
```

Answer (score 0):

Your client key is null.

Add your client key from your heroku settings.